# What is the basic difference between Bellman-ford and Floyd warshall algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

I just have one confusion that is it that in case of Bellman-ford we run it for n-1 times, which is no of edges while in Floyd warshall algorithm, we run it n times at each stage, so is it that we are excluding the source vertex in case of Bellman-ford and thats why we are running it for n-1 times, I am a bit confused in this with n and n-1, please clarify this.

Comment: Possible duplication of http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/158613/am-i-right-about-the-differences-between-floyd-warshall-dijkstras-and-bellman

Comment: I had gone through that still a bit confused a bit .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a purely computer science question and not a programming question.

Comment: Anyway, repeating what is written in the abovementioned link: Bellman-ford works for 1 source to all destinations, while Floyd-Warshall for all sources to all destinations. Both handle negative weights if there are no negative cycles (in which case no solution exist, and floyd tells you whether there is such a cycle or not).  The next time that you have a quesiton about *algorithms* instead of *programs* written in a specific programming language, ask your question on [computer science.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thankss , Now I got this and sorry for posting it here ,it won't be repeated

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The Bellman–Ford algorithm is an algorithm that computes shortest paths from a **single source vertex** to **all of the other vertices** in a weighted digraph 
whereas Floyd-Warshall computes shortest paths from **each node** to **every other node**.

Comment: Just to add on that, BF is different from Dijkstra in the sense that Dij can't handle negative weight, BF can't handle negative cycle.

Comment: If I wanted to know the shortest path from every source to every destination… I could just run bellman for every source vertex. Runtime should be E*V^2 … I guess that is worse than Floyd for a graph with many edges…